# Get string value in ansible list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

i've this list in my inventory :

```
employee_list:
- { emp_id: 101, name: Kiven, depatement: "id=10,job=IT", number: 00014646}
```

How i get the value of "Job" using Ansible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `job` is contained in the `depatement` subentry. You can parse the value of `depatement` via regex to extract the value of `job`.

```yaml
- name: Define employee_list
  set_fact:
    employee_list:
      - { emp_id: 101, name: Kiven, depatement: "id=10,job=IT", number: 00014646}
      - { emp_id: 102, name: Eve, depatement: "id=11,job=WelcomeDesk", number: 00014657}
      - { emp_id: 103, name: Kevin, depatement: "id=12", number: 00014667}


- name: Print out job from the employees
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item.emp_id }} has job {{ item.depatement | regex_findall('job=([\\w]+)', '\\1') | first | default('unknown') }}"
  with_items: "{{ employee_list }}"
```

Leads to the following output:

```
TASK [Define employee_list] ********************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Print out job from the employees] ********************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => (item={'emp_id': 101, 'name': 'Kiven', 'depatement': 'id=10,job=IT', 'number': 6566}) => {
    "msg": "101 has job IT"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'emp_id': 102, 'name': 'Eve', 'depatement': 'id=11,job=WelcomeDesk', 'number': 6575}) => {
    "msg": "102 has job WelcomeDesk"
}
ok: [localhost] => (item={'emp_id': 103, 'name': 'Kevin', 'depatement': 'id=12', 'number': 6583}) => {
    "msg": "103 has job unknown"
}
```

`regex_findall` always returns a list, if nothing is found an empty list (`[]`) is returned. `first` takes the first element from the list, `default` is a fallback if the `job` specification was not found and an empty list was returned.

[More about `regex_findall`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#searching-strings-with-regular-expressions) in the Ansible docs.

Answer (score 1):

Create the list below

```yaml
departments: "{{ employee_list|map(attribute='department')|
                               map('split', ',')|
                               map('map', 'split', '=')|
                               map('community.general.dict')|
                               list }}"
```

gives the list of dictionaries. The result is a list because there might be more items in the list *employee_list* as well.

```yaml
departments:
  - id: '10'
    job: IT
```

Get the list of the jobs

```yaml
jobs: "{{ departments|map(attribute='job') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  jobs:
  - IT
```

Get the first item `"{{ jobs|first }}"`

---

Example of a playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    employee_list:
      - {emp_id: 101, name: Kiven, department: "id=10,job=IT", number: 00014646}

    departments: "{{ employee_list|map(attribute='department')|
                                   map('split', ',')|
                                   map('map', 'split', '=')|
                                   map('community.general.dict')|
                                   list }}"
    jobs: "{{ departments|map(attribute='job') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: departments
    - debug:
        var: jobs
    - debug:
        var: jobs|first
```

---

If attributes might be missing use *json_query* instead of the *map* attribute. For example,

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    employee_list:
      - {emp_id: 101, name: Kiven, department: "id=10,job=IT", number: 00014646}
      - {emp_id: 102, name: Eve, department: "id=11,job=WelcomeDesk", number: 00014657}
      - {emp_id: 103, name: Kevin, department: "id=12", number: 00014667}
      - {emp_id: 104, name: Alvin, number: 00014668}
                        
    departments: "{{ employee_list|json_query('[].department')|
                                   map('split', ',')|
                                   map('map', 'split', '=')|
                                   map('community.general.dict')|
                                   list }}"
    jobs: "{{ departments|json_query('[].job') }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: departments|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: jobs|to_yaml
    - debug:
        var: jobs|first
```

gives (abridged)

```yaml
  departments|to_yaml: |-
    - {id: '10', job: IT}
    - {id: '11', job: WelcomeDesk}
    - {id: '12'}

  jobs|to_yaml: |-
    [IT, WelcomeDesk]

  jobs|first: IT
```